# How to get "else" not to loop

Tags: java

My code is a "guessing game" and so if you enter a southeast asian country to the input it will display a "you are correct" text but if not then otherwise, my problem is that the else loops whatever times the length of my array is that i put the countries in, how to stop loop plz?

Code--

```
package guessinggame;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
     String ans;
     String[] countries = {"Philippines", "Brunei", "Burma", "Cambodia", 
         "Timor Leste", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Vietnam"};
    
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
     
     System.out.println("Please enter a Southeast Asian country");
        ans = sc.nextLine();
       
        
        
        for (int x=0; x<countries.length; x++) {
        
        if (ans.equals(countries[x])){
                  
            
        System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is correct.");  
      
        
      }
        else System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is incorrect.");
}     
}
}
```

Comment: edited the code*
forgot to put the new one with the "else" on it

Comment: You need to `break` out of the loop in your `else`

Comment: it depends on the input that you enter justin , let's say if you enter "philippines" then it will print only once , if you enter "Vietnam" then it will print the else statement (length-1) times . If you need to print only once , then i suggest keep a flag and break its execution once you found it .

Comment: You can't tell whether the answer is incorrect until you've finished your loop. Instead of having your printlns in the loop, set a flag if a correct comparison is made and check it after the loop exits.

Comment: @QBrute, he needs to break out in the ```if``` Initialise a boolean ```answerIsCorrect```  to false before the loop. Set to true and break out when correct

Comment: BTW if you had the countries inside a `List` instead of an array, you could use `countries.contains(ans)` to check if the answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code takes user input, then within a loop it compares user input to one of the coutries and

- if match gives a message
- if not match gives a message

That means if your list is 20 entries long, in case of incorrect enty the user would be told so 20 times. For a correct entry, the user would be told 19 times that he is wrong and one time that he is correct.

What you need to do is:

- take user input
- loop over the list and find out if there is a match. Do not print a result during the loop
- after the loop has finished, print whether some match was found

You could set a variable

```
boolean found = false;
```

and set it to `true` once you found a match. Later your output can look like

```
if (found) {
    System.out.println("correct");
} else {
    System.out.println("incorrect");
}
```

If you want to tune your code terminate the loop as soon as you found a match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add break to your loop and a flag to can know if the user answer incorrect. Check the comments in my code.
I hope the code below will help you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String ans;
        String[] countries = {"Philippines", "Brunei", "Burma", "Cambodia", "Timor Leste", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Vietnam"};
        Boolean found = false; //Init the flag
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
        
        System.out.println("Please enter a Southeast Asian country");
        ans = sc.nextLine();
        
        for (int x = 0; x < countries.length; x++) {
            if (ans.equals(countries[x])){
                System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is correct.");
                found = true; //Change the flag to true if the answer is correct
                break; //Leave the loop so the flag can't change more
            }
        }
        
        // Check for the flag value. If the flag remains false, means that the answer is incorrect so will print the message below
        if (!found) {
            System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is incorrect.");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int x = 0; x < countries.length; x++) {
        if (ans.equals(countries[x])) {
            System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is correct.");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is incorrect.");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       
     String ans;
     String[] countries = {"Philippines", "Brunei", "Burma", "Cambodia", 
         "Timor Leste", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Vietnam"};
    
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
     
     System.out.println("Please enter a Southeast Asian country");
        ans = sc.nextLine();
       
        
        int flag =0;
        for (int x=0; x<countries.length; x++) {
        
        if (ans.equals(countries[x])){           
           flag =1;
            break;
        }
      
    } 
    if(flag==1){
     System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is correct."); 
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is incorrect.");
    }   
           
}
```

here you go

Comment: might as well use a boolean for the flag. And give it a meaningful name.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ans;
        String[] countries = { "Philippines", "Brunei", "Burma", "Cambodia", "Timor Leste", "Indonesia", "Laos",
                "Malaysia", "Singapore", "Thailand", "Vietnam" };

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a Southeast Asian country");
        ans = sc.nextLine();

        boolean available = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < countries.length; x++) {

            if (ans.equals(countries[x])) {
                available = true;
                break;
            } 
        }
        
        if (available) {
            System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is correct.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your answer (" + ans + ") is incorrect.");
        }
    }
}
```